# Bulk actions redirects to "options.php" page when clicked (WP_List_Table)

Tags: table, wp-list-table

I'm having a problem with WP_List_Table. I'm following a tutorial on internet (https://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/) because I need to display an table on my plugin page. The problem is that the Bulk Actions are not working, I already tried to use the original code provided by the link I just mentioned and I tried to follow another tutorial too. But, when I press the Bulk Action button, wordpress redirect me to wp-admin/options.php page, no matter which action bulk I press.

I don't have any idea why is this happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this error was occurring because I created this admin page in a wrong way. I just moved eveything related to this table to my main plugin php file and it is working now.